# Are “玩家一” and “玩家二” appropriate in the context of a coop videogame?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Google translate gave me  “玩家一” and “玩家二” as a translation for "player one" and "player two".

Are these the correct terms to use within a coop videogame? Or is there more context-specific terminology in this case, sort of how there is a different quantifier for different animals (一头牛，一匹马）?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"玩家一" and "玩家二"  short for "玩家一号" and "玩家二号" (player number one and play number two). The translation is correct and suitable in videogames. No one would confuse 玩家一(player one) with 一个玩家 (a player)

You can also use 控制者一， 控制者二 / 操纵者一， 操纵者二 (controller one, controller two)

Answer (score 0):

generally, you can say: 1号玩家, 2号玩家

If the video game is LOL like 5v5, you can say: XX队伍的一号位, 二号位, YY队伍的一号位,二号位.